# What does "com.apple.*" mean in plist titles

Tags: macos, java

I have a programmable Logitech mouse, which allows me to assign different configurations to different applications, but ONLY .app files, but I wish to assign a profile to Java, which is a binary not enclosed in a .app file.

When I nosed around into its preference file, it only refers to some sort of identifier associated for that app. For example, instead of saying `/Applications/Safari.app`, it would only reference it as `com.apple.safari`.

What does `com.apple.*` mean? Is it some sort of application identifier? And, if so, how can I find the one for Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That particular naming structure is known as "reverse DNS" naming. (Like Apple's website is at apple.com, so their plist entries are com.apple.) This is done so that items are sorted by manufacturer before product if you sort by name.

This nomenclature is used in Java packages (and other places) as well as OS X application identifiers.

If you want to specify Java as a whole, look for com.sun.* or com.oracle.*, as those are the two companies that have owned Java.

Comment: didn't, work, but maybe due to the " * " wildcard not being supposed in the pref file of my mouse settings, do u happen to know the full "reverse DNS"

Comment: It's whatever the company wants to put after the com.companyname prefix. Search your system for com.sun or com.oracle to see what has been registered for Java or your Java app.

Comment: I couldn't find anything when i searched my drive (i figured they are probably hidden) so i used pacifist to search inside apple's downloadable java rte and all i found was:    

com.apple.java.updateSharing.plist        

com.apple.java.InstallOnDemand.plist     

com.apple.java.updateSharing.plist    

com.aple.mrt.uiagent.plist     

com.aple.mrt.plist

Comment: Did you try `com.apple.java` to configure your mouse?

Answer (score 0):

The *com.apple.xxxx.plist* simply implies ownership of the plist file to Apple. plist files contain settings for *launchd* processes.